# Video Player - JS Error $ is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I purchased a video player and once implemented on my page it is causing issues with all my other JS functionality on the page.

In error console I am getting this message - "Error: TypeError: $ is not a function"

This is the video player script that is causing the issue.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var hap_players = [];    
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

            /* SETTINGS */
            var rvp_settings = {
                /* mediaId: unique string for player identification (if multiple player instances were used, then strings need to be different!) */
                mediaId:'player1',
                /* useDeeplink: true, false */
                useDeeplink:false,
                /*activePlaylist: Active playlist to start with. If no deeplink is used, enter element 'id' attribute, or if deeplink is used enter (data-address) deeplink string like 'playlist1'.  */
                activePlaylist:'playlist13',
                /*activeItem: Active video to start with. Enter number, -1 = no video loaded, 0 = first video, 1 = second video etc */
                activeItem:0,
                /* GENERAL SETTINGS */
                /*defaultVolume: 0-1 */
                defaultVolume:0.5,
                /*autoPlay: true/false (defaults to false on mobile)*/
                autoPlay:true,
                /*randomPlay: true/false */
                randomPlay:false,
                /* loopingOn: on playlist end rewind to beginning (last item in playlist) */
                loopingOn: true,
                /*autoAdvanceToNextVideo: true/false (use this to loop video) */
                autoAdvanceToNextVideo:true,
                /*autoOpenDescription: true/false  */
                autoOpenDescription:false,
                usePlaylist:true,
                useControls:true,
                /*autoHideControls: auto hide player controls on mouse out: true/false. Defaults to false on mobile. */
                autoHideControls:false,
                /*controlsTimeout: time after which controls and playlist hides in fullscreen if screen is inactive, in miliseconds. */
                controlsTimeout:3000,
                /*playlistOrientation: vertical/horizontal  */
                playlistOrientation:'horizontal',
                /*scrollType: scroll/buttons  */
                scrollType:'buttons',

                /* YOUTUBE SETTINGS */
                ytAppId:'AIzaSyDeqvaVCC5GEldPL1uOpI04h9sFoeH7WlY',/* youtube api key: https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application */
                ytTheme:'dark',
                ytShowinfo:true,

                /*playlistList: dom element which holds list of playlists */
                playlistList:'#playlist_list',

                /* showControlsInAdvert: true/false (show controls while video advert plays)  */
                showControlsInAdvert:true,
                /* disableSeekbarInAdvert: true/false (disable seekbar while video advert plays)  */
                disableSeekbarInAdvert:true,
                /* showSkipButtonInAdvert: true/false (show skip button while video advert plays)  */
                showSkipButtonInAdvert:true,
                advertSkipBtnText:'SKIP AD >',
                advertSkipVideoText:'You can skip to video in',

                logoPath: 'http://www.interactivepixel.net/images/jqueryPreviews/helper/apvplp_logo.png',
                logoPosition: 'tl',/* tl, tr, bl, br */
                logoXOffset: 5,
                logoYOffset: 5,
                logoUrl: 'http://www.google.com',
                logoTarget: '_blank',

                useShare: true,
                /*fsAppId: facebook application id (if you use facebook share, https://developers.facebook.com/apps) */
                fsAppId:'644413448983338'

            };

            hap_players[0] = $('#mainWrapper').aprvp(rvp_settings);

        });

    </script>
```

I tried wrapping that script with a "$(document).ready(function(){ });" but that did not work.  Still had JS issues and errors.

I have been trying to figure this out for 2 days now with no luck.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you actually including jQuery?

Comment: Make sure your jQuery include is before this code.

Comment: Yes I am.  Using: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js. It is the first JS I run on the page.

Comment: Then try to replace every dollar with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the dollar from this.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
```

Comment: Hi Tadeas. Tried removing the $.  Same issue.  This is very strange.

Comment: Send me a line of the error, or post it on jsfiddle, i will check it.

Comment: Hi Tadeas. Here is the page.  The error is actually occuring on line 336 the very next script function.  Here is a link to the site: http://www.webkomet.com/item/hobbyzone-sportsman-s

Comment: You will see none of the JS functionality is working including vote up, book mark, comments, etc.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your jQuery script tag is placed on your page before your video player script tag.